# how does nginx picks a resolver when there are multiple defined?

Tags: nginx, dns

How does nginx picks a resolver if you define several like:

```
...
resolver 108.x.x.x 120.x.x.x 19.x.x.x valid=30s;
...
```

Is it in a round-robin fashion? or there is some failover logic in there?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

According to the nginx document
http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#resolver

> Name servers are queried in a round-robin fashion.

They are using RR.

Comment: sorry, all i could find was articles predating 2013, also, do you know if there is some kind possibility to set some kind of failover?